Singer's ghost helps widow find love
I watched this movie on tv a time ago, about 10 years or more.
I was a kid and all I can remember is the channel, Cinemax Latin America, and some scenes that are already blurry images in my mind. Ah, also I think the movie was Brazilian or French:

It was about a girl that was going to get marry with this guy.
One day they went to a bar or restaurant and there was a singer performing, she payed all her attention to him the whole evening and I think he (the singer) did too.
They spoke, they fell in love, she left the guy and married the singer.
After they got married, he started touring and she was alone most of the time. 
One day he came back from tour and they spent time together and he told her he had to tour again, she was mad and they started arguing.
He laid in bed dramatically pretending he was dead and she got angry and left to the kitchen.
When he got up, he kind of felt weird, so when he looked to the bed there was him! Well, his body: he had die!
Funeral, crying, etc...
He became a ghost and I think there was this guy who was able to see him. After that, all I remember is the ending. He kind of plays cupid so the guy and his widow fall in love with each other.
I also don´t remember how but he comes back to life one day and makes love to her and they have a baby. 


This is the plot of the 2006 Brazilian comedy Stay with Me Tonight.

The musician and writer of the comic book "Ghost with Heart of Stone" Eduardo meets the gorgeous Laura, who is engaged and close to her marriage, in a bookstore and immediately they fall in love for each other. Sooner they get married and [...] are already experiencing their first crisis, mainly due to his hectic agenda and almost permanent absence. Used to playing dead to avoid long and heated arguments with Laura, Edu is caught completely by surprise when he actually sees himself dead, lying in bed. Now, after entering the world of the dead and having a secret to discover, he struggles to communicate with his lovely wife. The answer will come from the Rock's Heart Ghost. A spirit who doesn't enjoy others' company, but who has all the answers Edu is looking for.

You can find the trailer here, and here's the poster.

